# what does this mean char (*(*a[4])())[5]?

Tags: c++

Hi I came across the question in "Test your skills in c++".

Please let me know what does it  mean with an example?

***Edited Section***: Sorry for the extra parenthesis, edited & removed.

```
char (*(*a[4])())[5]
```

Comment: [Spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) wins again.

Comment: It's a syntax error due to unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: What was that site that translated gibberish _C declarations_ to human readable form?

Comment: Assuming you meant `char (*(*a[4])())[5];` cdecl.org says "declare a as array 4 of pointer to function returning pointer to array 5 of char"

Comment: @RetiredNinja:Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: IT means the person that wrote it pissed off at somebody and does not want you to be able to read the code.

Comment: is that a bad coder or good code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I cheated by removing what I think is an extra right-parenthesis and pasting the result into [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/).

`declare a as array 4 of pointer to function returning pointer to array 5 of char`

Comment: Can u please show me with an example.. Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: @Abhineet, I know what arrays, function pointers, function return values, and pointers to character arrays are but I can't think of a practical example that uses this particular combination of language features.

Answer (score 25):

Following the spiral rule (as linked to by chris), and starting with the identifier:

```
a
```

...is...

```
a[4]
```

...an array of 4...

```
*a[4]
```

...pointers to...

```
(*a[4])()
```

...a function taking no parameters...

```
*(*a[4])()
```

...returning pointer to...

```
(*(*a[4])())[5]
```

...an array of five...

```
char (*(*a[4])())[5]
```

...chars.

Sidenote: Go give the architect who came up with this a good dressing-down, then find the programmer who wrote this code without a comment explaining it and give *him* a good dressing-down. In case this was given to you as a homework, tell your teacher that he should have instructed you on how to use cdecl instead, or how to design code in a way that it doesn't look like madman scrawlings, instead of wasting your time with this.

Answer (score 13):

And another example... of what to never ever do in anything other than an example.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef char stuff[5];
stuff stuffarray[4] = { "This", "Is", "Bad", "Code" };

stuff* funcThis()   { return &(stuffarray[0]); }
stuff* funcIs()     { return &(stuffarray[1]); }
stuff* funcBad()    { return &(stuffarray[2]); }
stuff* funcCode()   { return &(stuffarray[3]); }

int main()
{
    char (*(*a[4])())[5] = { funcThis, funcIs, funcBad, funcCode };
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *a[i]() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `typedef`: makes your bad code better than my bad code! :)

Comment: I totally c++ified it with cout too! :)  The typedef is because I couldn't figure out how to declare the functions without it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Thanks for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 8):

And here's an example ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char a[5] = "abcd"; 
char b[5] = "bcde"; 
char c[5] = "cdef"; 
char d[5] = "defg"; 

char (*f1())[5] { return &a; }
char (*f2())[5] { return &b; }
char (*f3())[5] { return &c; }
char (*f4())[5] { return &d; }

int main()
{
        char (*(*a[4])())[5] = { &f1, &f2, &f3, &f4 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                printf("%s\n", *a[i]());
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.